# where does .net log authorization errors

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, authorization, owin

Where does .net log authorization errors, or does it? 
I am not seeing anything in the event viewer, or anywhere but I am not sure if I need to turn something on or what.

I am using the using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt UseJwtBearerAuthentication like so:

```
        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            TokenValidationParameters = tvps,
            IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
                {
                        new OpenIdConnectCachingSecurityTokenProvider("https://mydomain" + "/.well-known/openid-configuration")
                }
        });
```

And I have the Authorize attribute on a controller action. The jwt token is being passed and is valid so this SHOULD pass authorization but it is always failing, and I can't figure out how to debug.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imported NLog

In the configuration method of my StarUp Class I added

```
app.UseNLog((eventType) => LogLevel.Trace);
```

it started logging the errors to my Nlog File

Answer (score 1):

You could apply a global exception handler which should capture the exception you are looking for, along with any other uncaught exceptions from your application. Create a new filter similar to the following and add it to the HttpFilterCollection during startup

```
    public class CustomErrorAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Override of the OnException method
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filterContext">The FilterContext object</param>
        public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
             // access exception through "filterContext.Exception"
        }
    }
```

Comment: in that method you can log the exception to your log destination of choice, whether it's Event Viewer, a SQL table, etc